# Need assistance on setting up express route parameter

Tags: javascript, express, npm, pug

Hello this is my first time working with express, I am trying to create a portfolio website where I have a pug file called **project.pug** that contains html content that should render html content based on the ID of each project that I have on my Json file:

```
"data": {

    "projects": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "project_name": " ",
            "description": " ",
            "technologies": [ " "],

        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "project_name": " ",
            "description": " ",
            "technologies": [ " "],

        },
```

this is a route where I am trying to give the url an :id in order to change content based on each project's id, for example if I were to go to http://localhost:8000/project/1 I would like contents for project 1 to show up, if I were to go to http://localhost:8000/project/2 then info for that project should render and so on.

```
router.get('/project:id', (req, res) => {
res.render('project');
req.app.locals = data.projects.id;
const { id } = req.params //this variable represents the id of the project
const { side } = req.query; //this variable represents the page loaded with each project's info
```

});

but I am unsure on how to set the js logic in order change the content like that, can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to do this:

```
for (var project in data.projects){
  if(project.id === id){
    res.status(200).json(project);
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({message: "We don't have any project with this id"});
  }
}
```